# Grunt force watch?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I am running compass on grunt watch. I want grunt watch to always run tasks when it is initiated. I am calling it a force run but it might be called something else. Thank you in advance for solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

register a task to call the compass task before calling watch.

```
grunt.registerTask('dev', [ 'compass:dev', 'watch' ]);
```

to run from the command line just do

```
$ grunt dev
```

I'm using [**grunt-compass**](https://github.com/kahlil/grunt-compass) and it works fine.